# What are some abdominal exercises for a person with lack of a left iliac crest, left gluteal muscles, and scoliosis?

Tags: hip, rehabilitation, illness, spine, glutes

I've had a history with cancer, leaving me with no left [iliac crest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliac_crest) and minimal left [gluteal muscles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteal_muscles). Due to the surgery I have [scoliosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoliosis) as well.

I am 20 years old and want to take care of myself but I have yet to find exercises that don't hurt in the wrong way, especially abdominal exercises. I would like to work on my core and what gluteal muscles I have left. Please help.

Comment: In light of your medical history, and, the pain you've indicated, I think your best bet is working with a physical therapist.

Comment: Where did they reattach the tendons of your abdominus? Lower on the iliac?

Comment: It is very sensitive case that is why you must see a physician and physical therapist for sure. Get the first start in the hand of professionals then you can continue with your own intensity. Glad to see you here